# Django ForeignKey object does not get saved when using UpdateView with InlineFormSet

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have a hard time proceeding with a special case. There's an `UpdateView` which I use in order to serve a standard form (a `ModelForm` specifically) and an inline formset.

The `views.py` code looks like this:

```
class Contract(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = '/path/to/template.html'
    model = ContractModel
    form_class = ContractModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contract-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContractVerificationUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['student_form'] = StudentsFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['student_form'] = StudentsFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        student_form = context['student_form']
        if student_form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            student_form.instance = self.object
            student_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

When I open up this update view, the student's assigned on this contract model are all shown as expected, but when I edit something on them (for example I edit a student's name), and I hit the save button, it doesn't get saved. With my debugger I've confirmed that it reaches the line `student_form.save()`, which should update the object I guess, though it doesn't save itself. What's wrong with this?

It's possible that it's very easy to solve but my mind is really stuck at this point! Any kind of help or suggestions is greatly welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `form.is_valid()` before saving.

Edit your view like this,

```
def form_valid(self, form): 
    self.object = form.save(commit=False) 
    context = self.get_context_data() 
    student_form = context['student_form'] 
    if form.is_valid() and student_form.is_valid(): 
        self.object = form.save()
        student_form.instance = self.object 
        student_form.save() 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()) 
    else: 
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Comment: That makes sense, though I managed to fix my issue with another approach: in the event of POST request in `get_context_data()`, I changed `context['student_form'] = StudentsFormSet(self.request.POST)` to this `context['student_form'] = StudentsFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.get_object())` and now it works fine.